# How to get retrieved file data to display on chart in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on this project that retrieves stock data from a file on my computer and should display it in a chart when I click the load button. I've done most of the work but I am a bit unfamiliar with C#. What do I need to put in the "connectChart" method to make the data display in the data grid view? This is in Visual Studio .Net framework btw.

This is my main form class code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Stock_Project_Loader_Final
{
    public partial class StockLoader : Form
    {
        aCandlestickReader candlestickReader = null;
        List<aCandlestick> listOfCandlesticks = null;
        public StockLoader()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            candlestickReader = new aCandlestickReader();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = listOfCandlesticks = new List<aCandlestick>(512);
        }

        private void buttonLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String Period = String.Empty;
            if (radioButtonDaily.Checked ) { Period = "Day"; }
            else if (radioButtonWeekly.Checked) { Period = "Week"; }
            else { MessageBox.Show("Please select a period"); }
            listOfCandlesticks = candlestickReader.readStock(textBoxTicker.Text, Period, dateTimePickerStart.Value, dateTimePickerEnd.Value);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = listOfCandlesticks;

            connectChart();
        }

        public void connectChart()
        {
            //WHAT GOES IN HERE??????????????????????????????????????
        }
    }
}
```

Next I will paste my class designed for reading candlestick data:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Stock_Project_Loader_Final
{
    public class aCandlestickReader
    {
        const string dataFolder = "Stock Data";
        public List<aCandlestick> listOfCandlesticks = null;
        
        public aCandlestickReader()
        {
            listOfCandlesticks = new List<aCandlestick>(256);
        }

        public List<aCandlestick> readlistOfCandlesticks(string csvFilename, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
        {
            char[] separators = new char[] { '-', ',', '"' };
            //Get all the lines as a String array by reading all the lines
            String[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(csvFilename);

            //Skip the header
            String header = lines[0];
            //use first line to make sure the file is a proper candlestick file
            if (header == "\"Date\",\"Open\",\"High\",\"Low\",\"Close\",\"Volume\"")
            {
                //Create list of candlesticks with enough capacity for number of candlesticks read
                listOfCandlesticks = new List<aCandlestick>(lines.Length - 1);

                for (int l = 1; l < lines.Length; ++l)
                {
                    //Get the lth line
                    String line = lines[l].Trim();

                    //Split it base on ,-"
                    string[] subStrings = line.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                    //Parse the date info
                    int year = int.Parse(subStrings[0]);
                    int month = int.Parse(subStrings[1]);
                    int day = int.Parse(subStrings[2]);
                    //Build a date object from the first 3 substrings
                    DateTime date = new DateTime(year, month, day);

                    //Compare the date of this line with our range of desired dates
                    if (date.CompareTo(startDate) >= 0 && date.CompareTo(endDate) <= 0)
                    {
                        //Now get the other parts of the line: Open, High, Low, Close, and Volume
                        Decimal open = Decimal.Parse(subStrings[3]);
                        Decimal high = Decimal.Parse(subStrings[4]);
                        Decimal low = Decimal.Parse(subStrings[5]);
                        Decimal close = Decimal.Parse(subStrings[6]);
                        long volume = long.Parse(subStrings[7]);

                        open = Math.Round(open, 2);
                        high = Math.Round(high, 2);
                        low = Math.Round(low, 2);
                        close = Math.Round(close, 2);

                        //Create new candlestick with proper parameters
                        aCandlestick candleStick = new aCandlestick(date, open, high, low, close, volume);
                        //Add newly created candlestick to the list of listOfCandlesticks
                        listOfCandlesticks.Add(candleStick);
                    }
                }
            }

            return listOfCandlesticks;
        
        }

        public List<aCandlestick> readStock(String ticker, String period, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
        {
            //Create filename for the ticker by concatenating the dataFolder name, ticker name, period and extension
            String csvFilename = dataFolder + @"\" + ticker + "-" + period + ".csv";

            //Read the candlesticks and return them as the listOfCandlestick member
            listOfCandlesticks = readlistOfCandlesticks(csvFilename, startDate, endDate);

            return listOfCandlesticks;
        }
        
    }
}
```

Finally, my class for candlestick objects:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Stock_Project_Loader_Final
{
    public class aCandlestick
    {
        public DateTime date { get; set; }
        public Decimal open { get; set; }
        public Decimal high { get; set; }
        public Decimal low { get; set; }
        public Decimal close { get; set; }
        public long volume { get; set; }

        public aCandlestick()
        {
            date = DateTime.Now;
            open = 0;
            high = 0;
            low = 0;
            close = 0;
            volume = 0;

        }
        public aCandlestick(DateTime date, Decimal open, Decimal high, Decimal low, Decimal close, long volume)
        {
            this.date = date;
            this.open = open;
            this.high = high;
            this.low = low;
            this.close = close;
            this.volume = volume;
        }
    }
}
```

I simply don't know what to put in the method "connectChart" in the first class I pasted.

Comment: What's Visual Studio .NET Framework? Do you mean Winforms or WPF?

Comment: @Mushroomator winforms

Comment: _“What do I need to put in the "connectChart" method to make the data display in the data grid view?”_ - set the DGV’s data source to the data? Not sure what you’re asking for here